# Create parent with child, Case and Task

Tags: apex

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) you can create a parent and child record all in one dml statement. I can't seem to get it to work involving a case and a task. I get a compiler error of

> Field is not writeable: Task.What

```
Case caseReference = new Case(External_Id__c = '1234');

Case c1 = new Case (External_Id__c = '1234');

Task t1 = new Task (
   What = caseReference
);

insert new List<sObject>{c1, t1};
```

Comment: Create one External id field and the database.saveResult() you can create parent and child record. in task field api name is whatid

Comment: Just an FYI: If you're mixing sobjects in a `List<SObject>`, be careful to make sure that you don't switch objects too often. `insert new List<SObject>{c1, t1, c2, t2, c3, t3, c4, t4, c5, t5, c6, t6};` would throw `System.TypeException: Cannot have more than 10 chunks in a single operation` (each change between object types = 1 more "chunk"). Using `list.sort()` can alleviate this, but the safer method here would be to create separate lists for your SObjects and `addAll()` to an SObject list to guarantee the insertion order that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this for polymorphic fields (fields which reference two or more objects), because they are not native SObject records, but instead a special type of object called Name. This special object has a handful of fields, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_name.htm). Since it is not actually an SObject or a concrete type, but instead this special type, you can't do this in one go. There are very few fields like this, but you should be aware of this limitation for standard polymorphic fields, like Who, What, CreatedBy, LastModifiedBy, and Owner. You can use that technically normally in all other cases.